# Sharing across a multithreaded process

Tags: multithreading, process

Is an open file table shared across a multithreaded process? Why or why not?

I've tried approaching this from different ways but I'm struggling to determine the correct answer. I understand that a file descriptor table is not shared but I can't find anything relating to the open file table.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can one thread open a file, then tell another thread what the fd is and have that thread read or write it?  If that works, or doesn't, what would that tell you?